# How to avoid "Unknown audio device" prompt

Tags: unity, sound, 17.10, audio-jack

Everytime I plug my headset into my notebook, Ubuntu shows a "Unknown audio device" dialog asking me what kind of device I plugged in:

[image]

How can I avoid this dialog and use Headset as the default?